# Need help painting a desk top made out of MDF

Tags: painting, desk

I recently put together a quick desktop that I want to attach to a treadmill desk I am working on. I made it out of MDF. I want to paint it Matte Black! My question is how can I paint it in a way that it will be as resistant as possible to rubbing and scratching from desktop items like a laptop computer and other items that might be getting pushed around?

Answer (score 6):

MDF is essentially a sponge when it comes to painting it. So the first thing you need to do is prime it properly so that it doesn't absorb the paint. To prime it properly, use a non-water-based primer. These are known as solvent-based primers, or, more commonly called "oil-based" primer.

If you use a water-based primer, you end up with the sponge problem...the MDF will absorb all the water and your surface will end up with a rough raised-grain texture that you can't easily sand out.

Once you get a oil based primer on the MDF, you can then paint it as you wish.

As for resilience, note that MDF is soft. So no matter what you coat the surface with, you are going to be at the mercy of the substrate when it comes to heavy objects hitting it.

Fo starters, use a good quality paint. If you are particularly concerned, consider one of the epoxy based paints used to paint over laminate countertops/kitchen cabinets.

You may ultimately want to consider just putting a laminate on top of the MDF or just replace the MDF part with a section of countertop. Remember that MDF is soft, so that might be the weak part of the entire equation

Comment: This is good advice, but doesn't address the issue of how to make a matte black finish as resilient as possible.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks - I was curious if this had a better answer as well for a project I was considering.  Adding a separate veneer or laminate was all I could come up with.  MDF is so soft...

Comment: Would one of those wood hardening products work? I am guessing it absorbs in and hardens. Wonder if I try that and then an oil based primer?

Comment: @JohnDangerous the catch is you don't *want* it to absorb anything. That will cause it to well and raise the grain which is a pain to get smooth again. Honestly, I think it'd be best to just put something on top of the MDF...even a thin piece of plywood.

Comment: Ok good point. The problem is I already routed the edges which is a pain because I was reading that the edges is where MDF absorbs the most. If this doesn't work I will just cut another desktop out of some furniture grade ply I have in the garage. I probably should have done that in the first place. I was just being lazy lol.